# In-line extension installations no longer work in Chrome 56

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

After upgrading to Chrome 56 on Mac, it seems that inline Chrome extensions no longer prompt an installation anywhere on the web.

Does anyone know why?

[image]

Console gives the following error message:

```
Uncaught Error: A Chrome Web Store installation is already pending.
at Installer.install (extensions::webstore:20)
at Object.install (extensions::webstore:82)
at installChromeExtensionm ((index):643)
at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM1380 :1)
```

This seems to be an issue for all websites that have inline Chrome extensions (try grammarly.com, or momentumdash.com) - tested with multiple macbooks using Chrome 56.0.2924.87

Comment: See https://crbug.com/57370: it says to apply a pending Chrome update on chrome://help page.